# StreamReader Read Timeout

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

So the problem with StreamReader which works perfectly but returns error.

```
Error: timeouts are not supported on this stream
```

Well, I understand that StreamReader doesn't support this feature but I use Kendo UI. And the widget (Kendo Upload) catch this error and returns red color
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSyHe.png)

I load a file which is going to be parsed and saved in the database. Loading and reading the file after save parsed files to the database working properly. But this error disturbing me

Comment: A stack trace would probably help pinpointing who complains and why. Also, which version of .net this is, and what framework are you using (webapi?)